# BASH: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Tags: bash

I Have Been Searching For Answers But I Can't Find Any So Here's My Code In "od -a"

```
LiamBogur@LIAMBOGUR:/mnt/c/Users/traci/Desktop$ od -a ethedit2.sh
0000000   #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  nl   e   t   h   v
0000020   i   e   w   s   t   a   t   u   s   =   0  nl   e   t   h   v
0000040   i   e   w   m   o   d   e   =   0  nl   e   t   h   v   i   e
0000060   w   p   r   o   t   o   c   o   l   =   0  nl   w   h   i   l
0000100   e  sp   [  sp   $   e   t   h   e   d   i   t   s   t   a   t
0000120   u   s  sp   =  sp   1  sp   ]  nl   d   o  nl   i   f  sp   [
0000140  sp   $   e   t   h   e   d   i   t   m   o   d   e  sp   =  sp
0000160   0  sp   ]  nl   t   h   e   n  nl   i   f  sp   [  sp   $   e
0000200   t   h   e   d   i   t   p   r   o   t   o   c   o   l  sp   =
0000220  sp   0  sp   ]  nl   t   h   e   n  nl   n   c  sp   -   l  sp
0000240   -   v  sp   2   2   2   3  sp   |  sp   n   c  sp   l   o   c
0000260   a   l   h   o   s   t  sp   2   2   2   2  nl   f   i  nl   i
0000300   f  sp   [  sp   $   e   t   h   e   d   i   t   p   r   o   t
0000320   o   c   o   l  sp   =  sp   1  sp   ]  nl   t   h   e   n  nl
0000340   n   c  sp   -   l  sp   -   v  sp   -   u  sp   2   2   2   3
0000360  sp   |  sp   n   c  sp   l   o   c   a   l   h   o   s   t  sp
0000400   2   2   2   2  nl   f   i  nl   f   i  nl   i   f  sp   [  sp
0000420   $   e   t   h   e   d   i   t   m   o   d   e  sp   =  sp   1
0000440  sp   ]  nl   t   h   e   n  nl   i   f  sp   [  sp   $   e   t
0000460   h   e   d   i   t   p   r   o   t   o   c   o   l  sp   =  sp
0000500   0  sp   ]  nl   t   h   e   n  nl   n   c  sp   -   l  sp   -
0000520   v  sp   -   w   1   5  sp   2   2   2   1  sp   |  sp   e   t
0000540   h   e   d   i   t   i   p   =  nl   n   c  sp   -   l  sp   -
0000560   v  sp   2   2   2   2  sp   |  sp   n   c  sp   $   e   t   h
0000600   e   d   i   t   i   p  sp   2   2   2   3  nl   f   i  nl   i
0000620   f  sp   [  sp   $   e   t   h   e   d   i   t   p   r   o   t
0000640   o   c   o   l  sp   =  sp   1  sp   ]  nl   t   h   e   n  nl
0000660   n   c  sp   -   l  sp   -   v  sp   -   w   1   5  sp   2   2
0000700   2   1  sp   |  sp   e   t   h   e   d   i   t   i   p   =  nl
0000720   n   c  sp   -   l  sp   -   v  sp   2   2   2   2  sp   |  sp
0000740   n   c  sp   -   u  sp   $   e   t   h   e   d   i   t   i   p
0000760  sp   2   2   2   3  nl   f   i  nl   d   o   n   e  nl   e   c
0001000   h   o  sp   d   o   n   e  nl
0001010
```

all I can find next the the done is a nil character so I don't know how to fix it, please help

edit:
heres the raw code

```
#!/bin/bash
ethviewstatus=0
ethviewmode=0
ethviewprotocol=0
while [ $etheditstatus = 1 ]
do
  if [ $etheditmode = 0 ]
  then
    if [ $etheditprotocol = 0 ]
    then
      nc -l -v 2223 | nc localhost 2222
    fi
    if [ $etheditprotocol = 1 ]
    then
      nc -l -v -u 2223 | nc localhost 2222
    fi
  fi
  if [ $etheditmode = 1 ]
  then
    if [ $etheditprotocol = 0 ]
    then
      nc -l -v -w15 2221 | etheditip=
      nc -l -v 2222 | nc $etheditip 2223
    fi
    if [ $etheditprotocol = 1 ]
    then
      nc -l -v -w15 2221 | etheditip=
      nc -l -v 2222 | nc -u $etheditip 2223
    fi
done
echo done
```

Comment: programming tip - if you want your code to be more readable, indent each nested level of  `if` (or `while` or `for` etc) statements by a 2 or 4 spaces (or a tab).  That will make the structure and logical flow of the script to be clearly visible at a glance.  I'll edit your code to show you what I mean.

Comment: notice how the indentation makes it obvious that there's a missing `fi`.   BTW, i'd also recommend putting `; then` and `; do` on the same lines as the `if` or `while` statements rather than on a separate line...but that's a matter of subjective preference.  I think it makes the code much easier to read and the structure easier to see. some people don't.    Finally, you really  need to get into the habit of always double-quoting your variables.  e.g. use `"$etheditstatus"` rather than just `$etheditstatus`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't "close" this `if` with a `fi`:

```
if [ $etheditmode = 1 ]
```

Try indenting your code to make it easier for yourself (and others) to read, and check out shellcheck.net.